# $AB = BA = I$. Why is it not true that $B$ must equal $A$?

Tags: matrices

$A$ and $B$ are square matrices such that $AB = BA = I$, where I is an identity matrix. Which one of the following statements is not true?

- A. $ABA=A$
- B. $AB^2A=I$
- C. $B$ must equal $A$
- D. $B$ is the inverse of $A$
- E. both $A$ and $B$ have inverses

Please explain why the answer is C

Comment: tell us what you've tried.

Comment: Have you try to prove/unprove each statement?

Comment: A title like "Year 12 Matrices" does not provide any information about the post. Try to write a more descriptive title. Also, try to write your post with MathJax. It might make the post clearer.

Comment: BA=-AB in normal matrices but here BA=AB ie they obey commutative law so they must be equal for this hence A must be equal to B

Comment: @ArchisWelankar "BA=AB ... hence A must be equal to B" **Huh??**

Comment: @Archis: invertible matrices obviously aren't necessarily equal........ the question asks which "is not true."

Comment: Do you understand why, if I give you a real number $x$, then $x$ isn't always equal to $1/x$?

Comment: So its an involutory matrix so i too have an example A(0 -1                                  0  0    and  B ( 1 1 0 0 ) so AB =BA=0

Comment: Sorry but dunno how to use maths latex for matrices

Comment: @ArchisWelankar Try `$\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}$`. Also see http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @ArchisWelankar Also, in general $BA \neq -AB$. What is "normal" about a matrix that satisfies $BA = -AB$?

Answer (score 2):

Let $A = \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 \end{pmatrix}$
and $B = \begin{pmatrix} \frac12 & 0 \\ 0 & \frac12 \end{pmatrix}$.

What is $AB$? What is $BA$? Is $A = B$?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the $1\times1$ matrices $\left[\begin{matrix}2\end{matrix}\right]$ and $\left[\begin{matrix}\frac12\end{matrix}\right]$.

Answer (score 0):

If B *must* equal A for all AB = I, then $A^{-1} = A$ for *all* invertible  matrices, and $A^2 = I$ for all invertible matrices.

It is simply an absurd statement.